# Home Icon not appearing on Toolbar

Tags: android

I have tried every answer in stack overflow but nothing works. Code is given below, please tell me if I miss anything:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.suleiman.material.R;
import com.suleiman.material.adapter.SimpleRecyclerAdapter;
import com.suleiman.material.model.VersionModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnimateToolbar extends AppCompatActivity {
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    int mutedColor = R.attr.colorPrimary;
    SimpleRecyclerAdapter simpleRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animate_toolbar);

         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Suleiman Ali Shakir");

        ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.header);

        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);
                collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor);
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.scrollableview);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        List<String> listData = new ArrayList<String>();
        int ct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < VersionModel.data.length * 2; i++) {
            listData.add(VersionModel.data[ct]);
            ct++;
            if (ct == VersionModel.data.length) {
                ct = 0;
            }
        }

        if (simpleRecyclerAdapter == null) {
            simpleRecyclerAdapter = new SimpleRecyclerAdapter(listData);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleRecyclerAdapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_animate_toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/header"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

android.R.id.home button is not appearing for toolbar. I have used every single thing but then also its not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you set..
Use it accordingly

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_good);
toolbar.setTitle("Title");
toolbar.setSubtitle("Sub");
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: @Priya Can you test it on a real device, i had the same issue, though it was on an emulator, it dint happen on a real device.

Comment: I tested on real device but then also its not working. Now I use an imageview inside toolbar and made it to act as home icon.

Answer (score 0):

This can also help.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_home);
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Ya I know its correct but its not working when implementing toolbar for parallax scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the toolbar goes behind. So you need to call the below method in your  `Oncreate()` method. This will fix the problem

```
  [toolbar object].bringToFront();
```